# Reading a string whose length is not known

Tags: c

How to read several strings in a loop, each of whose length is not previously known ? I tried the following but its not working as desired.

```
int main()
{
    int j, i = 0;
    char c;
    char *buf = malloc(20);
    size = 20;
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        i = 0;
        while(1)
        {   
            if(i == size)
            {
                buf = realloc(buf,size+10); 
                size += 10;
            }               

            char c = getchar(); 

            if(c == '\n') 
                break;  

            buf[i] = c;
            i++;        
        }
        buf[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

It works only if i am taking these strings as inputs. But say i have a scanf("%d",&j) right before i take string inputs then pressing enter for this scanf would make my first string empty

Comment: How does that not work? It just reads one character at a time, doesn't matter if it's a digit character or not.

Comment: @ugoren yes i do. read the code carefully

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  
It works only if i am taking these strings as inputs. But say i have a scanf("%d",&j) right before i take string inputs then pressing enter for this scanf would make my first string empty.

Comment: If you have an error with a scanf before, please post this in your code, your current code should not see any problems with integer because it does not know of any integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you using e.g. `scanf` before reading your strings in the way you do in the question, is that the `scanf` call *leaves* the newline in the input buffer. So the first character fetched by `getchar` is this newline, leading to your first line being empty.

You can solve this in a couple of ways:

- Tell `scanf` to discard any trailing whitespace by using

  ```
  scanf("%d ", &i);
  ```

  Notice the space after the format code.
- Manually skip whitespace:

  ```
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && isspace(c))
      ;
  /* `c` is now a non-space character or EOF, put it back if it's not EOF */
  if (c != EOF)
      ungetc(c, stdin);
  ```

Comment: @user2545792 You're to quick to comment, check my answer again :)